# How to use http patch request in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am trying to use PATCH request.

below is the code which i am using. and it is like ladder of if statements

```
@PatchMapping("/updateInvoiceByEmail/{email}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Invoice>> updateInvoiceByEmail(
                @PathVariable String email,
                @RequestBody Invoice invoice) {

        return invoiceRepository
        .findByEmail(vendorEmail)

        .flatMap(existing -> {
            if (invoice.getInvoiceStatus() != null) {
                existing.setInvoiceStatus(invoice.getInvoiceStatus());
            }
            if (invoice.getCanRaise() != null) {
                existing.setCanRaise(invoice.getCanRaise());
            }
            if (invoice.getAttachmentId() != null) {
                existing.setAttachmentId(invoice.getAttachmentId());
            }
            if (invoice.getInvoiceId() != null) {
                existing.setInvoiceId(invoice.getInvoiceId());
            }
            ... and so on.
            return invoiceRepository.save(existing);

        })
        .map(updatedInvoice -> new ResponseEntity<>(updatedInvoice, HttpStatus.OK))
        .defaultIfEmpty(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
```

I am using 
Spring WebFlux and mongodb

How can i make shorter and cleaner.

Thanks

Comment: you cant make it cleaner since you have designed the api to have this logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection if you want to reduce number of lines although reflection is always last thing that you should do. What I would do is to move this if - get - set logic in separate component(in separate class or method). Aside from that, I would just like to mention that simplicity is not the only problem here. Assume that `null` is valid value sent by client, you will need some mechanism how to detect if value is not sent or you explicitly wanted to set `null` value. Some example of moving this code to separate component would look something like this:

```
class InvoiceAssembler {
   public static assemble(Invoice existing, Invoice newInvoice) {
     if(newInvoice.getInvoiceId() != null) {
         existing.setInvoiceId(newInvoice.getInvoiceId());
     }
     ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way I see you could improve is if you use a UpdateDTO for the fields that are most likely to be updated and therefor reduce the amount of fields you have to check.

[Good description of how you use UpdateDTO here](https://www.baeldung.com/http-put-patch-difference-spring)

Otherwise you are left with reflection but I don't know if that would make your code more readable or more confusing instead.